# Do I have always put my static methods inside the class?

Tags: c#, class, nested, extension-methods

I have something like this:

Now i need to write some static methods too which is context specific, like when I'm using the objects in WinForms I don't need html related static methods. Is there a way to describe static methods else where other than nesting them within the object class like I can do with the Extension methods?

Comment: You should consider using properties and constructors for your classes.  Separate classes for the conversions might also be simpler than extension methods for everything...

Answer (score 0):

> Now i need to write some static methods too which is context specific, like when I'm using the objects in WinForms I don't need html related static methods. Is there a way to describe static methods else where other than nesting them within the object class like I can do with the Extension methods?

You can place them in their own class, separate from the "object" on which they're acting.  This is effectively all an extension method does - it's a static method in a separate class.

Answer (score 0):

You can put extension methods in any number of static classes, there's nothing particularly special about your `PSVitaExtentions` class.  The extension methods are callable as long as you have pulled in their namespace, so as @griegs says it may be wise to put your second set of extension methods in a different namespace.

Comment: I've planned to put them in a different namespace. I was hoping to get something like Download.Get.DB.ByQuery("Select * from...") methods without writing them nested in Download class.

Comment: If this is meant to expand your question, what do you mean by "nested" and why can't you write something like that?

Comment: I can, but I'll be using these object definitions in other applications where those static stuff may not be necessary. I was just checking if this is a wrong practice that's all.